# Looking for suggestions on how to more efficiently clean up Python NoneType values returned by a web api

Tags: python-3.x

I’m querying a web api, that without much consistency, returns json objects with varying number of dict() keys, and varying number of data type structures inside of them. Depending on a given query, returned objects will have a number of dict() keys ranging between 15 and 28. Nested within them, will be some objects of the same name, but different data type. Some will come back as lists, some as dict()s, etc., and most importantly, some of them will occasionally come back as NoneType.
After receiving the data, I'm either creating a pandas dataframe (for future visualization), or sending it directly to a local sqlite3 database.
Neither sqlite or pandas “like” dealing with NoneType objects, without throwing exceptions, etc.

So far, I have been hammering it a newb way (don’t bash me, only been learning Python for a couple of months), by adding it as individual items to the for loop, one by one, as the errors related to “can’t iterate on NoneType” pops up. After putting a number of for loops below, the code is running without errors, but I’m certain there is a better way to do this…

Question: given the dynamic and the unpredictable nature of data types returned by the web api, what is the best mechanism to address the NoneType issue for all objects that could be of NoneType, instead of using individual key item.get('name') lookup for each potentially problematic one?

Below is my “for loop” to deal with  the “None”s:

#Clean up returned json from None and erroneous NUL values, that would otherwise will give an error when iterating or trying to upload it to sqlite

```
for item in s_results['matches']:
    if item.get('tags') is None:
        item['tags'] = ' '
for item in s_results['matches']:
    if "\x00" in item.get('data'):
        item['data'] = ' '
for item in s_results['matches']:
    if item.get('location') is None:
        item['location'] = ' '
for item in s_results['matches']:
    if item.get('product') is None:
        item['product'] = ' '
for item in s_results['matches']:
    if item.get('version') is None:
        item['version'] = ' '
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension can be used to iterate the dictionary and replace all `None` values with a space:

```
d = {1: False, 2: None, 3: "Text", 4: None}
replaced = {k : " " if v is None else v for k, v in d.items()}
# Prints {1: False, 2: ' ', 3: 'Text', 4: ' '}
```

Since you're trying to replace an inner dictionary, you could subscript into it during the assignment and access:

```
s_results['matches'] = {k : " " if v is None else v
                        for k, v in s_results['matches'].items()}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Carcigenicate ! Where were you a week ago when I was pounding my head against the wall trying to figure this out on my own... :)

Comment: @gjmemel Here :). I'll note though, I shouldn't really have answered this, as it's not really on topic. For improving working code, [codereview.se] is a better place, although they require working [mcve]s of code, along with context. In the future, just be aware that "Looking for suggestions" questions likely won't be well received here.

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of that. Appreciate the guidance. Will behave according to the rules next time.